# How to concatenate variables like this in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

eg. correct sample -

```
f.write("\t" +connection_name+ "\t =" + qs.connection_name + "\n")
```

what I'm trying to do -

```
f.write("\t" +current+ "\t=" +qs.current+ "\n")
```

//here `current = 'connection_name'`

How to concatenate in this kind - `qs.current` so that it prints as qs.`connection_name`'s value

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Actually was using it to print the value of object so it was showing - object has no attribute 'current'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
getattr(qs, current)
```

So in the context of your code

```
f.write("\t" + current + "\t=" + getattr(qs, current) + "\n")
```